# Filter files out of a folder, and copy them to a other folder

Tags: copy, zip, structure, directory, 7zip

I ask a few questions here and every time I am very pleased with the answers, so here we go again.

I have three folders inside the folders the files have the same names except for the file structure:

> 1 folder with .zip
>   1 folder with .7zip
>   1 folder with different folders

I really would like to get all the matching files from the .zip. 
So .zip is leading and I am looking for a batch file that will copy the files from the other folders.

I really hope this makes any sense :) English isn’t my first language.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find` command.

`find . -regex '.*\.zip' -exec cp {} target_dir \;`

Comment: Thanks!   so this will transfer all the matching files from the folder with .zip files to another folder?

Comment: It will copy files ending in .zip to target_dir.